# How to copy sheets to another workbook using vba?

Tags: excel, vba, templates

So, what I want to do, generally, is make a copy of a workbook. However, the source workbook is running my macros, and I want it to make an identical copy of itself, but without the macros. I feel like there should be a simple way to do this with VBA, but have yet to find it. I am considering copying the sheets one by one to the new workbook, which I will create. How would I do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: An alternative, which I've decided to use is this: Manually strip out the macros and save that workbook as a "Template." Not is the office sense of a template, but just generally speaking, then you can open that and make a copy to modify when necessary.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Someone over at [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=59938&page=1) answered a similar question. Basically, you just copy each sheet one at a time from Workbook1 to Workbook2.

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

    Dim currentSheet as Worksheet
    Dim sheetIndex as Integer
    sheetIndex = 1

    For Each currentSheet in Worksheets

        Windows("SOURCE WORKBOOK").Activate 
        currentSheet.Select
        currentSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks("TARGET WORKBOOK").Sheets(sheetIndex) 

        sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1

    Next currentSheet

End Sub
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this code out and instead just adopted the linked example to your problem. If nothing else, it should lead you towards your intended solution.

Comment: why `.activate`and `.select`? , dump it. Also you want to loop in `Thisworkbook.worksheets`. I am not sure if it would work with hidden sheets (select would definitely cause an error)

Comment: @BryanF `.select` is not actually necessary for `.copy` to work, it is actually only necessary that the "source workbook" be active - ergo `Thisworkbook.Activate` \ `Sheets(1).copy(Before:=OtherWorkbook.Sheets(1))` would copy the first sheet from  `ThisWorkbook` to `OtherWorkbook`

Answer (score 56):

I would like to slightly rewrite keytarhero's response:

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

Dim sh as Worksheet,  wb as workbook

Set wb = workbooks("Target workbook")
For Each sh in workbooks("source workbook").Worksheets
   sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.sheets.count) 
Next sh

End Sub
```

---

Edit: You can also build an array of sheet names and copy that at once.

```
Workbooks("source workbook").Worksheets(Array("sheet1","sheet2")).Copy _
         After:=wb.Sheets(wb.sheets.count)
```

**Note**: copying a sheet from an XLS? to an XLS will result into an error. The opposite works fine (XLS to XLSX)

Comment: I agree, this solution is better.

Comment: What about if one of the sheets references another sheet?

Comment: @shlgug Then use Brad's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865542/78522

Answer (score 12):

You could saveAs xlsx. Then you will loose the macros and generate a new workbook with a little less work.

```
ThisWorkbook.saveas Filename:=NewFileNameWithPath, Format:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, it would probably work, as long as it didn't generate an error.

Comment: Clever approach, indeed

Answer (score 6):

I was able to copy all the sheets in a workbook that had a vba app running, to a new workbook w/o the app macros, with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your macros are in modules, maybe [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) will help. After copying the workbook, just iterate over each module and delete it

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write

```vba
Worksheets.Copy
```

in lieu of running a cycle.
By default the worksheet collection is reproduced in a new workbook.

It is proven to function in 2010 version of XL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Copy
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="Path(Ex: C:\Reports\ClientWiseReport.xls)"ReadOnly:=True


    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Next Sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one you might like it uses the Windows FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) to browse to a closed workbook on your desktop, then copies all of the worksheets to your open workbook:

```
Sub CopyWorkBookFullv2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim closedBook As Workbook
Dim cell As Range
Dim numSheets As Integer
Dim LString As String
Dim LArray() As String
Dim dashpos As Long
Dim FileName As String

numSheets = 0

For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
       Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet1"
   End If
Next

Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim MyString As String

fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

  With fileExplorer
     If .Show = -1 Then 'Any file is selected
     MyString = .SelectedItems.Item(1)

     Else ' else dialog is cancelled
        MsgBox "You have cancelled the dialogue"
        [filePath] = "" ' when cancelled set blank as file path.
        End If
    End With

    LString = Range("A1").Value
    dashpos = InStr(1, LString, "\") + 1
    LArray = Split(LString, "\")
    'MsgBox LArray(dashpos - 1)
    FileName = LArray(dashpos)

strFileName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & FileName

Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
closedBook.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
numSheets = closedBook.Sheets.Count

        For x = 1 To numSheets
            closedBook.Sheets(x).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        x = x + 1
                 If x = numSheets Then
                    GoTo 1000
                 End If
Next

1000

closedBook.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
closedBook.Close
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

Sub Get_Data_From_File()

```
     'Note: In the Regional Project that's coming up we learn how to import data from multiple Excel workbooks
    ' Also see BONUS sub procedure below (Bonus_Get_Data_From_File_InputBox()) that expands on this by inlcuding an input box
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
         'copy data from A1 to E20 from first sheet
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:E20").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SelectFile").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
        
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

or this one:

Get_Data_From_File_InputBox()

```
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim ShName As String
Dim Sh As Worksheet
On Error GoTo Handle:

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    ShName = Application.InputBox("Enter the sheet name to copy", "Enter the sheet name to copy")
    For Each Sh In OpenBook.Worksheets
        If UCase(Sh.Name) Like "*" & UCase(ShName) & "*" Then
            ShName = Sh.Name
        End If
    Next Sh

    'copy data from the specified sheet to this workbook - updae range as you see fit
    OpenBook.Sheets(ShName).Range("A1:CF1100").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
```

Handle:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
MsgBox "The sheet name does not exist. Please check spelling"
Else
MsgBox "An error has occurred."
End If
OpenBook.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

both work as