# Save Specific Sheet as New Workbook with Values only

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Ok. I have been rattling my brain now for hours and scrolling through the internet for even longer and I can't seem to work out how to save a specific sheet in a work book as a new workbook with values only. 
Quick back story, I have a work book with heaps of pages with one being a report generator. The "Standard Report" sheet consist of graphs and tables that refer to cells in other sheets in the workbook. I want to create a macro that saves the "Standard Report" sheet as it's own workbook with the current values only.

Is this even possible? If someone could give me a hand or throw me some helpful links that would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend copying the sheet to a new workbook, breaking links in that workbook, and then saving. Consider something like the below (untested, intended to point you in the right direction only).

```
Sub StaticCharts()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim scoll As Series


'Assumes the active worksheet contains the charts; change below to an absolute reference if possible
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'Adds a new workbook

sh.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1) 'Copies sheet with charts to new workbook

'Delete empty sheets in destination workbook
On Error Resume Next
wb.Sheets(4).Delete
wb.Sheets(3).Delete
wb.Sheets(2).Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'Break links in all charts
For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
    For Each scoll In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
        scoll.Values = scoll.Values
        scoll.XValues = scoll.XValues
        scoll.Name = scoll.Name
    Next scoll
Next cht

End Sub
```

See this (old) article for more information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213443

Additional resources:

- [How to copy sheets to another workbook using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863940/how-to-copy-sheets-to-another-workbook-using-vba)
- http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/8/15/loop-through-all-charts-in-activeworkbook
- http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154000-Break-Links-to-Source-in-Both-Workbook-and-Chart

Comment: Thank you for the Coding! @Nick, It's a great starting point. The "Break links in all charts" isn't working 100% but i can work on that.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped!