# Create a new workbook with some of the sheets of the old one

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with around 10 sheets, and I would like a macros that creates a new workbook with 4 sheets of the original.

I have this:

```
Sheets("1").Range("A1:xfd200").Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")
```

But that only creates a new workbook with one of the sheets I need.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy sheets to another workbook using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863940/how-to-copy-sheets-to-another-workbook-using-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make copies of the other worksheets as well.

```
'copy first ws to no location to create the workbook then loop through
'and make copies of the others
dim ewb as workbook, w as long
with thisworkbook
    .worksheets(1).copy
    set ewb = activeworkbook
    for w = 2 to 4
        .worksheets(w).copy after:=ewb.worksheets(ewb.worksheets.count)
    next w
    'work with the new workbook as ewb 
end with

'alternately, copy them into a new workbook all at once
Dim wss As Variant, nwb As Workbook

wss = Array("Sheet12", "Sheet13", "Sheet14", "Sheet15")  '<~~ desired worksheets to copy

With ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets(wss).Copy
    Set nwb = ActiveWorkbook
    'work with the new workbook as nwb
End With
```