# Copy specific sheets from a workbook to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy specific sheets from a workbook to another workbook. i used below codes but not working.

```
    Sub copy_fromwb()

    Workbooks("LLT RM Sep'19.xlsm").Sheets("R5903078-Sep'19").Copy _
        after:=Workbooks("LLT RM Oct'19.xlsm").Sheets("R5903078-Aug'19")

    End Sub
```

Run time error

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863940/how-to-copy-sheets-to-another-workbook-using-vba/6865661)

Comment: The command syntax is fine. However, you have 4 references in that and all of them can fail. Why don't you split the command like `Set wb = Workbooks("LLT RM Sep'19.xlsm")` then `Set sh = wb.Sheets("R5903078-Sep'19")`, etc, and then run it step by step to see wich command fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy sheets to another workbook using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863940/how-to-copy-sheets-to-another-workbook-using-vba)