# Copy Multiple Worksheet in another worksheet after the 1st Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have a file with multiple worksheet as per image 1 below

I need to copy all the sheets with sheet name in another workbook but after the 1st sheet as per Image 2 and then run macros on that filese

I cannot use basic as below as new tabs will be added every month to 1st worksheet. Hence please advise

```
Windows("Master Data with Doc number.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("00689").Select
Cells.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Master Data Template.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("00689").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at my Q and the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30575923/4961700

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I recommend to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865661/3219613).